# How to fix this error: cannot find symbol - method setText(java.lang.String)

Tags: java, methods

I am making a seat monitoring system using java PL. I have this method in my ComputerSeats class:

```
public void occupySeat()
{
    seatOccupied[station-1] = true;
    mtr.showArrayIdVal().setText(stud.showField().getText());
    seat[station-1].setBackground(Color.red);
    occupiedSeatCounter++;
}
```

the ShowArrayIdVal contains a `Jlabel[] object`, the value of this label is "Vacant Station", I used `setText(stud.showField().getText())` to change "Vacant Station" to the value that I have inputted using `JTextField`. But then, whenever I compile it, It contains an error which states that it cannot find `settext()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  `mtr.showArrayIdVal()` is returning a `JLabel` Object your code should work fine.

I assume that `mtr.showarrayidval()` is returning `array of Jlable objects`. so, you should be getting the object on the `index` and then call `setText(...)`.

```
   for(JLable jl: mtr.showArrayIdVal()) {
        jl.setText(..)// do what ever you are setting here.
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

Cant tell exactly without the stacktrace and more code, but my guess is that mtr.showArrayIdVal() doesn't return JLabel instance.

if mtr.showArrayIdVal() returns JLabel[] (array of JLabel objects) you should call it

```
mtr.showArrayIdVal()[i].setText(stud.showField().getText())
```

where i is integer and the compilation would pass - of course you must declatre and initialize i.

Answer (score 0):

use `mtr.showArrayIdVal()[0].setText(stud.showField().getText());`

incase of list

use `mtr.showArrayIdVal().get(0).setText(stud.showField().getText());`

Comment: does arrays have a get(index) method??, unless you are returning an list of jLabel.. :P

Comment: @subodh.. Still not ok.. I think you should look at some tutorials on using array and ArrayList.. I'll edit the code for you..

Answer (score 0):

> ShowArrayIdVal contains a Jlabel[] object, the value of this label is
>   "Vacant Station"

As you are telling that `showArrayIdVal` contains `JLabel[]` array... So, you cannot invoke `setText()` on an array..

Rather you can iterate over the returnd array, and invoke `setText` on individual labels..

```
for(JLabel label: mtr.showArrayIdVal()) {
     label.setText("Your text");
}
```